# B2C Custom Policy error with client certificates

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using B2C custom policies to federate to the external Azure AD Identity Provider.
I was successful before when federating with client secrets, but trying to switch to certificates now, and getting an error **"No url encoding for asymmetric keys"**.  Here is what I did as a Proof Of Concept:

1. Generated a new self-signed certificate in Azure keyvault
2. Exported it into the .pfx and .cer files.
3. In B2C created a Policy key and uploaded the .pfx certificate there
4. In custom policy referenced that policy key

```
<CryptographicKeys>
       <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MyB2CPolicy" />
</CryptographicKeys>
```

5. In Azure AD app registration under Certificates and Secrets uploaded the .cer file (with public key)
6. Tried to connect using MSAL.js
7. Received a "server error" with correlation id, which in appinsights shows up as

```
     {
       "Key": "SendErrorTechnicalProfile",
       "Value": "OpenIdConnectProtocolProvider"
     },
     {
        "Key": "Exception",
        "Value": {
          "Kind": "Handled",
          "HResult": "80131500",
          "Message": "An invalid OAuth response was received: \"{0}\".",
          "Data": {
            "IsPolicySpecificError": false
          },
          "Exception": {
            "Kind": "Handled",
            "HResult": "80131515",
            "Message": "No url encoding for asymmetric keys",
            "Data": {}
          }
        }
      }
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to convert the certificates to another format before uploading? Perhaps .pem? The problem is, there is no documentation I could find on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C can use client certificate to redeem authorization codes at the `/token` endpoint of a federated IdP.

See the reference for the [OpenId Connect Technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile#metadata) on all supported options.

Based on Azure AD doc for certificate credential [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) and Metadata options available, in the OIDC Technical profile, use the following options:

- **token_endpoint_auth_method**: `private_key_jwt`
- **token_signing_algorithm**: `RS256`

In the [cryptographic keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile#cryptographic-keys) section, reference your certifcate that you uploaded into B2C Policy Keys:

- **assertion_signing_key**: `B2C_1A_MyB2CPolicy`

Remove the `client_secret` reference.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!