Client Certificate on Access Token request in Azure B2C Custom Policy for OAuth 2.0 3rd Party Provider
I am working on an Angular SPA that uses Azure B2C with a 3rd party identity provider which implements a non-standard OAuth2.0 codeflow for authentication. It does not implement ODIC either.
I have created a custom policy with Technical Profile to encompass the workflow for this authentication and user journey but unfortunately the provider has thrown us a curveball. The "AccessTokenEndpoint" provided by them is secured by a) a proxy and b) certificate authentication. The certificate is in addition to the standard client_secret authentication. I have managed to navigate around the proxy by adding custom claims schemas to the access token call but I am now stopped by the requirement of a client certificate.
The custom policy is as follows.

I have scoured the documentation and the internet and while B2C does seem to allow you to set up a client certificate for custom API calls (using the API connector) within the UserJourney, it makes no mention of this for the actual authentication steps.
Has anyone got any information on this at all?

I've had the same issue and I fixed it by using the comment here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679221/b2c-custom-policy-error-with-client-certificates

thanks for the link. I tried something similar to this but had the problem that the endpoint I was trying to access had both client_secret AND a certificate. I eventually went down the route of setting up my own secure proxy which handles the API call to the token endpoint and adds both auth methods to the http call. I then use my proxy endpoint as the "token endpoint" in the B2C policy. Not elegant I concede but it worked.
